# Is it possible to use "foundation for css" components with "foundation for application"?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've started to use "Foundation for css". Then when I decided to migrate my application to "foundation for apps", I have been surprised to see that all components of "foundation for css" are not in "foundation for apps".

Is it possible to use (for example) the sticky bar from "foundation for css" to my "foundation for app" application ?

If it is possible what should I do? Copy css files? Add  `$(document).foundation();` somewhere ?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will be missing some foundation styles, just overwrite components folder with foundation components.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/scss/foundation/components
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/tree/master/scss/components

basically its the same components with less styles and options, and some components do not exist int he app.

Comment: I am not sure that it is a good idea to overwrite foundation-apps by foundation for site. I will wait for the next version of foundation for app. I hope it will come soon.